# Update an array of objects mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, api, mongoose

I know that this question might be beginner level but I haven't find anything yet.
I would like to update an array of objects with `mongoose`. I am interested in updating one object from the users array according to the index.
Usually one user is getting changed at a time.

Here is my schema:

```
 _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
name: { type: String, required: true },
gm: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    required: true
},
users: [],
```

I want to update an object in the users array which is like this:

```
{
    id:"5bcb7c7ff9c5c01b9482d244",
    gm:"5bcb7c7ff9c5c01b9482d246",
    name:"room 1"
    users: [
        {
            id:"5bcb7c7ff9c5c01b9482d243",
            stats:{
                power:10,
                mobility: 5,
                vitality: 20
            },
            bag:{itemSlot1: "Knife",itemSlot2:"Sword" }
        },
        {
            id:"5bcb7c7ff9c5c01b9482d241",
            stats:{
                power:10,
                mobility: 5,
                vitality: 20
            },
            bag:{itemSlot1: "Knife",itemSlot2:"Sword" }
    ]
}
```

I want to perform a `patch` or a `post` request to update one user each time from the user array. i am getting the id of the user from `req.body` to match it with my db.

My request is like this:

I would like to update based on a request like this:

```
data = {
  stats={
    power:"10",
    vitality:"20"
   }
}
```

Thanks in advance,
Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do an update like this:

```
YourSchema.update({
  'users.id': '5bcb7c7ff9c5c01b9482d243'
}, {
  $set: {
    'users.$.stats': data.stats
  }
})
```

Which would update the first user with id `5bcb7c7ff9c5c01b9482d243` `power` stats to `20`

This is using the [`update`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) with the [`$` positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/index.html) to update the element in the array.

Just have it set up in your post/patch request.

Comment: Sure I updated the answer. Just `set` with the `data.stats` then.

Comment: and what if i get a bag object as well and some key pairs are missing from the request?

Comment: That is something you can do in your request before the `update` call. You can default values if the `data` does not have what you want etc. I am just providing the request to mongoose not the entire request handler.

Comment: can i make a dynamic $set though and update only the values i get?

Comment: You could simply compose your set object and just add the props you want to update like this: `{
    'users.$.stats.power': data.stats.power,
    'users.$.stats.other': data.stats.other
  }` based on what you have in `data.stats`

Comment: the truth is that i am doing this in anonter way cause in request i send the whole user object

`let userIndex = room.users.findIndex(user => user.id === req.body.userId)
        room.users.splice(userIndex, 1)
        room.users.push(req.body)
        room.save`